# Project builds in command line and visual studio but not in rider on mac m1pro MSB3971

Tags: c#, macos, apple-m1, rider

My project builds fine in visual studio for mac but refuses to build in rider. I get the following error in rider:

```
0>Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1232,5): Error MSB3971 : The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
0>------- Finished building project: DataMigrationAgent. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
```

The only reference to NETFramework i found was here:

[image]

My csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\net6.0</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="7.0.0" />
 
        <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.9.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="FreeSpire.Doc" Version="11.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />

        <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />

        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.2.2" />

        <PackageReference Include="SharedKernel" Version="1.2.1" />


    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

adding this text so my post isn#t mostly code, not sure what details i should add here.

It builds fine in terminal and vs for mac, but i really would prefer using rider!

It also doesn't load all dependencies correctly in rider, but i am unsure if that's related

Comment: Try removing NETFRAMEWORK from define constants. Also can Rider build any project (for example new empty console one)?

Comment: Your project file looks good (and why command line build succeeded), but your screen shot looks bad (like the other comment indicated). That's very much related to Rider settings.

Comment: Yes I managed to build a different net 6 Project in rider. Unfortunately the define constants bit is not editable.